# The function I am in is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, this, settimeout

I have an object in a javascript. A method in the object is called from outside the object. I want this method to call itself (kind of recursion but not quite) after 200ms untill a condition is fullfilled.

```
this.setSearchResult = function(data){
    if(initiated){
        doSetSearchResult(data);
    }else{
        console.log("Map is not initiated yet. Waiting 200 ms");
        setTimeout(function(){setSearchResult(data);}, 200); // <- Error
    }
}
```

Calling setSearchResult is done this way:

```
mapView = new MapView(imageData);
mapView.setSearchResult(data);
```

The error I get is `ReferenceError: setSearchResult is not defined.`

One way to overcome the error is by changing the setTimeout call to this:

```
setTimeout(function(){mapView.setSearchResult(data);}, 200);
```

But I find that rather ugly (even though it would probably work in my application).

Is there a proper way of doing it? Do I have to skip using setTimeout in setSearchResult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
this.setSearchResult = function(data){
    if(initiated){
        doSetSearchResult(data);
    }else{
        var _this = this;

        console.log("Map is not initiated yet. Waiting 200 ms");
        setTimeout(function(){_this.setSearchResult(data);}, 200); // <- Error
    }
}
```

It is because you are in a callback function so you do not have access to the setSearchResult function.

Answer (score 1):

`setSearchResult` is a method of your MapView object. You therefore have to call it as such. Inside the method itself, you can use the keyword `this` to reference the object the method belongs to.

Using `this.setSearchResult` would work if you would use it directly inside your method. But using it inside your `setTimeout` callback function, it would reference the `window` object, because `setTimeout` is a method of `window`. To work around this, store `this` in another variable and use it to point to the right object.

```
// Store this in a variable called self
var self = this;

setTimeout(function() {
    // Inside this function "this" points to window, because setTimeout
    // is a method of window. Use the previously declared self instead.
    self.setSearchResult(data);
}, 200);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It realy helped me understand.